# Windows Server 2012 Printer spools but does not print

Tags: printer, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an application on our server, the application's job is to print a file. When I run the application I see the printer start spooling in the printer window, I see files (briefly) get written to c:\windows\system32\spool\Printers before being deleted but nothing comes out of the printer.

I have printed a test page from the printer so I know it's working (the document I want to print is a pdf and I've printed that through acrobat acrobat to the same printer on the server so I know it's not an issue with my document either). I have run the application on my local windows 7 machine and it works fine. I have checked the error log and there are no errors.

I'm at a total loss, what might be stopping the printer from printing? (The printer is a sharp mx-2640N pcl6, I've checked the drivers too)

EDIT:

The application I'm trying to run is a bespoke console application created in c# using the system.printing to handle printing. It passes every test I throw at it (apart from the print, and this works everywhere apart from Windows Server 2012), all its peripheral functions work fine on the server.

I am remoting into the server and launching the application from there, the application is on the server. The application appears to run fine.

When I print from acrobat reader I get the following event IDs, that result in a print; 800 (spooling), 801 (printing), 307 (confirmation), 805 (rendering), 842 (confirmation - sen to printer)

When I "print" from my application I get 800 (spooling), 310 (Deleting)

Comment: When you RDP have you configured the session to load your local printers (like you can connect your remote drives). When you "print" from your application is the system default printer still your Sharp printer?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Print Processor if it is configured correctly. I had the same issue and it turned out wrong print processor was set after migration.